# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found - nm reports symbol found

Tags: c, ruby, cmake, symbols

Fairly abstract question here, as I don't know quite where to start my own investigations.

I have a C package constructed with CMake that produces librpdb.so; I have a Ruby Gem set up for the same library, which produces rpdb.bundle.

When used in Ruby, I get this:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _RPDB_RuntimeStorageController_sharedInstance
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rpdb-0.1.0/lib/rpdb/rpdb.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

When I look into the library, nm reports:

```
000000000000ea40 T _RPDB_RuntimeStorageController_sharedInstance
```

So it appears that the symbol is indeed in the library. Why, then, would binding fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, linking wasn't occurring at the level of the first library, although it wasn't reporting as much because the headers were found appropriately.

[More details regarding why this was occurring for my circumstances, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304681/basic-cmake-question-linking-fails)

[and also, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992068/building-a-python-shared-object-binding-with-cmake-which-depends-upon-external-l/997615#997615)